# http-proxy-middleware blocking web page

Tags: node.js, http, express, http-proxy

Do you have any idea why when opening the following web page on the browser it keeps loading (blocking)?

http://localhost:3002/

If you place a `return;` just before the line: `res.writeHead = (...args) => { writeHeadArgs = args; };`, the page works normal but the logic of the code is not executed. If you place the `return` after that line, it keeps loading forever.

**Run**

```
$ node server.js
```

**server.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware');

function bodyTransform(body) {
    return body.replace('World', 'People');
}

var onProxyRes = (proxyRes, req, res) => {

    const end = res.end;
    const writeHead = res.writeHead;
    let writeHeadArgs;
    let body;
    var buffer = new Buffer('');

    proxyRes.on('data', (chunk) => {
        console.log("inside: .on('data', ...)");
        buffer = Buffer.concat([buffer, chunk]);
    });
    proxyRes.on('end', () => {
        console.log("inside: .on('end', ...)");
        body = buffer.toString('utf8');
    });

    res.write = () => { };
    res.writeHead = (...args) => { writeHeadArgs = args; };

    res.end = () => {
        const output = bodyTransform(buffer.toString());
        res.setHeader('content-length', output.length);
        if (writeHeadArgs)
            writeHead.apply(res, writeHeadArgs);
        end.apply(res, [output]);
        console.log('after: end.apply(res, [output]);');
    };
}

const portApp01 = 3001;
const app01 = express()
app01.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello World!');
});
app01.listen(portApp01, () => {
    console.log('app01 is listening on port: ' + portApp01);
});

const portProxy = 3002;
const appProxy = express()
appProxy.use(proxy({ target:'http://localhost:3001', onProxyRes: onProxyRes, changeOrigin: true }));
http.createServer(appProxy).listen(portProxy, function () {
    console.log('appProxy is listening on port: ' + portProxy);
});
```

This is the output I get on the terminal:

```
[HPM] Proxy created: /  ->  http://localhost:3001
app01 is listening on port: 3001
appProxy is listening on port: 3002
inside: .on('data', ...)
inside: .on('end', ...)
after: end.apply(res, [output]);
```

Any idea on how to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: You have any error in terminal?

Comment: nop, no errors, just normal log info. did you try the code?

Comment: Yeah, I tried and you used bable?

Comment: At which point in the code does it begin to hang? You can figure this out either using a debugger, or using console.log if you'd prefer. It's obviously entering the function since your "return" is making it work. So there must be something bombing out that isn't being picked up.

Comment: I modified my code above and the terminal output to answer your question. As you can see it reaches even the end of the function: `res.end = () => { ... }`. Probably I'm ommiting something like a: `next()` but I don't know how to get that function (with: `http-proxy-middleware`) in order to invoke it.